# Can't pass a vector returned from a function to a function expecting a reference to a method

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2012, stl, ubuntu-12.04

I have this function...

```
std::vector<int> GetAVector();
```

used as an argument to this function:

```
void ExpectingAVector(std::vector<int> &vec);
```

So this construction:

```
ExpectingAVector(GetAVector());
```

DOES compile on Visual Studio 2012, but does NOT compile on G++, Eclipse Indigo, Ubuntu 12.04

Error message:
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector’ to ‘std::vector&’

So if g++ cannot support this, what are my options? All likely alternatives are less elegant

a) declare a vector and pass it by reference to both GetAVector and ExpectingAVector?
b) have GetAVector return a pointer to vector and have ExpectingAVector accept it? Messy cleanup
c) have ExpectingAVector accept a vector object and accept the inefficiency?

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Wow, this really compiles in VS2012? It's definitely not allowed by the standard and such a basic rule, I would never have imagined any half decent compiler to get this wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ExpectingAVector( GetAVector() );
                  |
                  +-------------Creates a temporary vector<int> object (rvalue)
```

Use :

```
void ExpectingAVector(const std::vector<int> &vec);
```

temporary object cannot bind to non-const references

This is an extension on Visual C++ to allow such behavior, which can be disabled by some flag <sub>(*I don't know which ones*)</sub>

You can also use move-semantics with `void ExpectingAVector(std::vector<int> &&vec ) { }` 
if you're okay with  C++11 .

Comment: Lovely lucid answer :) So my only "one-line" options are move semantics?

Comment: @AndrewS. yes and no. You can do with temporaries, but can't bind lvalues  then

Comment: @AndrewS. If you change your function to take a const reference as P0W wrote, you should be able to compile it in both compilers.

Comment: @AndrewS. with rvalue reference (`&&`) you can use `std::move()` on lavlues